# Apache, fast cgi, c++. Как установить unix сокет на который отправлять запросы?

Tags: c++, apache, fastcgi

В коде написал

```
int sockId = FCGX_OpenSocket("fcgi.sock", 20);
```

В конфигурации

```
SetHandler fcgid-script
Options +ExecCGI
AllowOverride None
Options None
Require all granted
```

Comment: просто укажите путь полностью и проблем не будет https://habrahabr.ru/post/154187/

Comment: @KoVadim, спасибо за ответ. Но в статье которую вы указали настраивается nginx. Хотелось бы узнать как указать путь к сокету на apache.

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_fcgi.html

Comment: @KoVadim, Спасибо! А нет ли ничего подобного на Apache 2.2?

Comment: Для 2.2 вроде нет. Но он уже считается устаревшим